# Approximate Identity: Projections

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

**Problem**

Given a C*-algebra $\mathcal{A}$.

Denote the positive open unit ball by: $\mathcal{B}^+$

Then it has an approximate identity:
$$A\in\mathcal{A}:\quad\|A-AE\|,\|A-EA\|\stackrel{E\to1}{\to}0\quad(E\in\mathcal{B}^+)$$

Denote the self adjoint projections by: $\mathcal{P}$

Do they form an approximate identity, too:
$$A\in\mathcal{A}:\quad\|A-AP\|,\|A-PA\|\stackrel{P\to1}{\to}0\quad(P\in\mathcal{P})$$

**Disclaimer**

This thread is meant as summary. For more informations see:

- [SE blog: Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)
- [MSE meta: Answer own Question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4680/79762)

*(The second especially reveals the opinion of the community!)*

Comment: Can I ask what the point of such things is? You seem to flood MSE with self-answers. You treat MSE as a blog. I think you should instead get a blog and post your thoughts there.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Please, have a look at the links I added.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: It is ridiculous: The time I forget to add the disclaimer, people start complaining.

Comment: I understand that you want to share results but I think it's better suited in an actual blog format. I enjoy these questions but at the same time, I think it's better to read in a blog setting where you can give more background and real thoughts on the matter.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Well, I don't think so, IMO. ;) But anyway, I still have a recent open question: [Approximate Identity vs. Adjoined Unit](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1084690/79762) Can you help me there, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, they don't!**

First, consider the operator algebra generated by the right shift:
$$\mathcal{A}_R:=\overline{\langle\{R\}\rangle}\subseteq\mathcal{B}(\ell^2(\mathbb{N}))$$

Then the collection of selfadjoint projections is even empty!

Next, consider a proper selfadjoint projections adjoined: $$\mathcal{A}_{RP}:=\overline{\langle\{R,P\neq1\}\rangle}\subseteq\mathcal{B}(\ell^2(\mathbb{N}))$$

Then the collection still does not form an approximate identity:
$$\mathcal{P}_{RP}=\{P\}:\quad\|R-RP\|=1$$

Finally, that won't change until adjoining the identity as:
$$P\in\mathcal{P}:\quad\|R-RP\|\equiv1\quad(P\neq1)$$
*(That is because the right shift is isometric!)*

**Remark:** From operator theory one knows they form only strong approximate identities...

Comment: Every C*-algebra admits an approximate unit in $A^+$, but some C*-algebras are projectionless.

Comment: @Phoenix87: I didn't know that before. So that I was really wondering about! Thanks for your comment. :)

Comment: Sure but perhaps $C_0(\mathbb R)$ is a simpler one :)

Comment: @Phoenix87: Please, go ahead with this as another answer! ;)